# Data Import from Relational to multidimensional in Sql Server 2012

Tags: ssas

We have project in maintenance phase,now client want to use multidimensional concept. So I have created another database ( Dim and fact tables) then created Cubes.
My question is how to import data from relational db to multidimensional database?

Comment: What kind of multidimensional db should you use: MOLAP, ROLAP, HOLAP?

Comment: I am new to it but i guess I used MLOP

Answer (score 0):

In MOLAP model data is copied to multidimensional database during Process action: [Processing Analysis Services Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175634.aspx)

First, you need to import all necessary meta data to Data Source View: tables, views, their relations.

Second, add dimensions, which are used on axis and as filters.

Third, build cube (add measures from measurable fields of fact tables, add dimensions by linking their keys to corresponding keys of fact tables).

Finally, process this objects. This action creates files with data (measure groups of measures) and index files (aggregated values per each individual member to speed up retrieving data, also pre-aggregated used-defined combinations).